Как переписать регулярное выражение, что с квадратными скобками удаляло запятые в строке
System.out.println(integerList.toString().replaceAll("^\\[|\\]$", ""));

Как переписать регулярное выражение, что с квадратными скобками удаляло запятые в строке?
Пример строки, для которой нужен шаблон:
[38.5, 33.8, 33.7, 37.2, 38.4]


Из вашего текста не понятно что вы хотите удалить квадратные скобки и запятые, оставить квадратные скобки и удалить запятые, также хотелось бы увидеть пример поля которое нужно отредактировать с помощь регулярного выражения

Добавьте в вопрос примеры что на входе и что на выходе. Поставьте метку языка программирования (возможно это Java?)

выводятся элемента массива в консоль с помощью Arrays.toString [38.5, 33.8, 33.7, 37.2, 38.4], надо их вывести без квадратных скобок и запятых,  вышеуказанное регулярное выражение удаляет квадратные скобки, не получается дописать, чтобы и запятые удаляло....это Java

А не проще ли сделать наоборот - искать в строке числа формата \d+\.\d+? Если нужно и без точки иногда, то можно альтернативный шаблон с просто \d прописать или часть \.\d+ сделать не обязательной. И потом соединить их через пробел. Или именно при выводе сразу по-другому сделать как-то, не через Arrays.toString. Вы боретесь сейчас с проблемой, которую сами же создали, непонятно, зачем это вообще. И подходите к проблеме не с той стороны. Удалять что-то из строки, чтобы в ней что-то найти - это неправильный путь. Нужно делать шаблон поиска нужных данных в строке.

В общем, смотрите лучше куда-то в сторону String.join при выводе массива.

@CrazyElf Соглашусь со всем сказанным выше, полностью, мало представляю зачем нужен такой функционал но тут не будут разбираться с чужим тех заданием.

Изменить саму регулярку достаточно "просто":
// с использованием набора символов внутри []
System.out.println(integerList.toString().replaceAll("[,\\[\\]]", ""));
// с использованием альтернатив |
System.out.println(integerList.toString().replaceAll(",|\\[|\\]", ""));

Однако здесь в общем случае есть риск удаления ненужных символов, например, для чисел с плавающей точкой при использовании русской локали запятая будет использоваться в записи самого числа, или при выводе списка строк, содержащих какие-либо из удаляемых символов.
Поэтому, как заметили в комментариях, правильнее было бы, вместо "развлечения" с регулярными выражениями, вывести поэлементно список с использованием нужного разделителя, благо для этого существует масса способов:
// построчный вывод
// для списка
integerList.forEach(System.out::println);
// для массива
Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(System.out::println);


// вывод в одну строку, разделённый парой пробелов
integerList.forEach(n -> System.out.print(n + "  "));

// преобразование чисел в строки поэлементно + объединение при помощи Stream API
String str = integerList.stream()
    .map(Objects::toString)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
System.out.println(str);

// String::join для списка строк
System.out.println(String.join(" ", strList));
// аналогично для массива
System.out.println(String.join(" ", strArray));


Вот как вы можете это сделать для JS


let str = "[38.5, 33.8, 33.7, 37.2, 38.4]";
str = str.substring(1, str.length - 1);
str = str.replace(/,\s*/g, " ");
console.log(str);



для Java
String str = "[38.5, 33.8, 33.7, 37.2, 38.4]";
str = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);
str = str.replaceAll(",\\s*", " ");
System.out.println(str);


Большое спасибо всем, все советы по делу, есть такая проблема у меня , люблю себе жизнь усложнять... но всё-таки: так я могу удалить скобки replaceAll("^\[|\]",""); так запятые replaceAll(",",""), как я могу эти выражения объединить?


выводятся элемента массива в консоль с помощью Arrays.toString [38.5, 33.8, 33.7, 37.2, 38.4], надо их вывести без квадратных скобок и запятых, вышеуказанное регулярное выражение удаляет квадратные скобки, не получается дописать, чтобы и запятые удаляло

Предложу такой вариант...


let str = "[38.5, 33.8, 33.7, 37.2, 38.4]";
const r = /[\[\],]/g
str = str.replace(r, "");
console.log(str);



